# How can I fix it about delegate and protocol?

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I want to use  table view cell's data in the collection view. Those are in same controller. How can I do that ? When I try this, delegate comes nil and nothing happens.Nevermind CellForRowAtIndexPath,numberOfRowsInSection methods.

```
protocol DataDelegate {
func dataInfo(survey:Survey)


}

import UIKit

class SurveyViewControllerLeftTableView: UITableView,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

var survey = [Survey]()

var  myDelegate : DataDelegate? 

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.dataSource=self
    self.delegate=self

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


     myDelegate?.dataInfo(survey[(indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!])

}

}


import UIKit

class BottomCollectionView: UICollectionView,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,DataDelegate {


var surveyBottomCollection = [Survey]()



override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()


self.delegate = self
self.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return surveyBottomCollection.count
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell  : BottomCollectionViewCell = dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BottomCollectionViewCell

    cell.surveyQuestionNumberLabel.text = surveyBottomCollection[indexPath.row].questionNumber
cell.surveyQuestionDescriptionLabel.text = surveyBottomCollection[indexPath.row].questionDescription

    return cell

}

func dataInfo(survey: Survey) {
print(survey.questionDescription)

    surveyBottomCollection.append(survey)
    self.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Tolga, what i understand here that you need to reuse `CollectionView` Cell into `UITableView` but i don't think that it will directly work like above mention code. You need to create `UITableView` Cell and assign data what you want on that cell from Collection view.

Comment: I already created UITableView Cell, how can I assign? Can you give me simple example ? I'm confused.

Comment: let me explain to you, There are views;collection and table in one controller. I want to when I click the table view's cell all information within to send collection view cell's data.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you need to create `UITableView` custom cell or need to create a cell in `storyboard` and then use the below code to get `CollectionView` Cell data into your table view cell.

And at the same time while select any cell `tableview:didSelect` will call and at did the select function you need to add that tableview array object in one another `Array` and use that array in you `Collection` view cell.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

            // Replace Beow line with your costume cell outlets 
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

           //Like this Probably same like collection view or what ever you want to rename it in TableViewCell
           cell.surveyQuestionNumberLabel.text = surveyBottomCollection[indexPath.row].questionNumber
           cell.surveyQuestionDescriptionLabel.text = surveyBottomCollection[indexPath.row].questionDescription

            return cell
 }
```

**Update :**

```
// Use this method to get the selected objects and add them into a new array.
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           // Add Your object with indexPath.row and reload your collectionView here 
        }
```

Hope above code will help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Ok, I  already assigned custom cells for table view and collection view. How I can show cell.surveyQuestionNumberLabel.text ,  cell.surveyQuestionDescriptionLabel.text  into collection view cell ? Would I explain clearly ?

Comment: As you know ,I can't use segue for this.Because of one controller. I think protocol,delegate can help me but how ?

Comment: as you are in same screen you didn't need nay delegate protocol . What you need is just create one more array and this array fill when you click on table view cell and while click on cell add selected object in new array and reload your collection view thats it.

Comment: Something like that ?     
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)   {
          
        
        let bottomCollection = BottomCollectionView()
        
           bottomCollection.surveyBottomCollection = survey
        
         bottomCollection.reloadData()
        
    }

Comment: yes if you have data in your survey and you want to use into Collection View than its fine, but don't create `CollectionView` new object in tableView:didSelect but use `IBOutlet` object of that collection view there.

Comment: So, in Controller Class to override tableview:didSelect func ?

Comment: Can you help me,please?

Comment: Yes in controller class you need to override that table view did select function and use what i suggest.

Comment: Is it  possible to override custom table view in UIViewController?